# List appending is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, append

```
def get(i, x):
i = 0
numbers = []
while i < x:
    print ('At the top i is %d' % (i))
    numbers.append(i)

    i = i + 1
    print ("Numbers now: "), numbers
    print ("At the bottom i is %d" % (i))

print ("The numbers: ")

for num in numbers:
    print (num)
get(1,6)
```

So when I call the function this is the result:

```
At the top i is 0
Numbers now: 
At the bottom i is 1
At the top i is 1
Numbers now:
At the bottom i is 2
At the top i is 2
Numbers now: 
At the bottom i is 3
At the top i is 3
Numbers now: 
At the bottom i is 4
At the top i is 4
Numbers now: 
At the bottom i is 5
At the top i is 5
Numbers now: 
At the bottom i is 6
The numbers: 
0
1
2
3
4
5
```

So why `"Numbers now: "` is not showing anything? Is there something wrong with `print` statement, the `append` function or what? I'm lost here, appreciate any help.

Comment: Because it should be inside the closing parenthesis ;)

Comment: Thanks man, by the way why do I keep getting downvoted for?

Comment: I'm not a downvoter, but perhaps it's because in Python 3.x `print` is a **function**, not a statement and can therefore only output things it is passed as arguments...or perhaps it's because it seems like you should have been able to figure this problem out yourself.

Answer (score 2):

You need to include the `numbers` inside of the parenthesis in the print statement.

`print ("Numbers now: ", numbers)` instead of `print ("Numbers now: "), numbers`